# Python Citrix Sharefile Token Request giving 400 error

Tags: python, python-requests, citrix, sharefile

I am trying to make a simple request to get the access token from Citrix ShareFile, but it's throwing 400 error.

I am going exactly as it's mentioned in the documentation, except changing Python2 code with HTTPLib, with Python3 code with Requests. The code is:

```
url = 'https://{my_domain}.sharefile.com/oauth/token'

headers = {'Content_Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
params = {'grant_type':'password', 'client_id':my_client_id, 'client_secret':my_client_secret, 'username':my_username, 'password':my_password}

response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers = headers)
print(response.status_code, response.reason)
```

I get the following response:

```
400 Bad Request
```

I also added urllib.parse.urlencode to params, but am still getting the same response error

```
response = requests.post(url, params=urllib.parse.urlencode(params), headers = headers)
```

Request guidance on what am I doing wrong. TIA

Answer (score 0):

It could be the password, in the context of Sharefile it means app_password and not the password used to login to website. Or response_type to 'code'.

SF Auth is through OAuth2 with a GrandType: [OAuth2 Password Grant](https://api.sharefile.com/gettingstarted/oauth2password)

This way works for me:

```
url = 'https://{my_domain}.sharefile.com/oauth/token'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = {
    'response_type': 'code',
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': '<YOUR CLIENT ID>',
    'client_secret': '<YOUR SECRET>',
    'username': '<USERNAME>',
    'password': '<APP_PASSWORD>'  # not regular password to login using web
}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Response contains token and refresh token.

Answer (score -1):

When I add content-type my issue solved.

Check and add valid content-type

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).